# Why website printed with Chrome is using mobile layout?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, media-queries

In Chrome, when printing to A4 paper, it is rendered with **568px** media query width.

Try printing a responsive website such as [The Verge](http://www.theverge.com/) or [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and you will see in the preview that it's using the mobile layout (see image below).

[image: The Verge printed with Chrome]

While in Firefox, it uses around **900px** (see image below).

[image]

**Is there a way to make it print Desktop layout**?

I know I can work around this by changing my mobile breakpoint to 568px, but I need my website to break in 768px for iPad.

Comment: You must have a `@media print` condition in your stylesheet which contains the mobile CSS too

Comment: @McNab Sorry my question isn't clear, I just editted my question (second last line) to make it more clear. I want Chrome to print the desktop layout.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Verge *isn't* using a mobile layout for printing. It's using its own print layout. If you inspect the page whilst emulating a media of `print` you'll see a load of `media="print"` declarations. This is loaded in through the HTML:

```
<link href="..." media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

If you want a website to look different when printing than it does on mobile, simply specify `screen` within your mobile media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    ...
}
```

When printing, the `screen` declaration will be ignored, thus completely ignoring your *mobile* media query.

Comment: Oh Thanks! so that's what `screen` for. I keep seeing it in other's people code but not using it because it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 14):

Just add this to your style sheets

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 330mm 427mm;
    margin: 14mm;
  }
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that fixed my issue with Chrome going on mobile layout when Print is enabled !

Comment: Glad it helped u :)

Comment: Finally a solution that works! This will print pages with the desktop design, even in chrome.

Comment: This is an experimental feature, up to the browsers you use to implement it. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size

Comment: Thanks, this solution is really working in my case.

Comment: Seems to be working for people not me, I tried changing the .container {} to my div class did not work, I tried it as it is, still nothing. Is it possible there's another css overriding it? If so, how do i make your solution the priority?