# Bootstrap 4 - printing using chrome browser prints in mobile format

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, bootstrap-4, responsive

I developed a responsive webpage using bootstrap4. The display on different browsers works as expected. When I try to print from a desktop using Safari browser, the page gets printed in desktop view, when I do the same using chrome browser, the page gets printed in mobile view. Any ideas on how I could make it print in desktop view from chrome? Thanks

Comment: Please include your code. A screenshot would also help.

Comment: <div class="mt-5 row">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 mx-0">
        Left side heading
        <hr class="hr--thin"/>
        Left side body
        <hr class="hr--thin"/>

        <div class="mt-4 d-none d-md-block">
            <small class="h6 text-center">
                <div class = mt-1>End of left side</div>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 ">
        Right side heading
        <hr class="hr--thin"/>
        Right side body
        <hr class="hr--thin"/>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: This is how it displays on desktop https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBDjU.png
This is how it displays on mobile.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/G85Rd.png
When trying to print from chrome browser.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tm5T.png
When trying to print from safari browser. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TnZJ.png

Image 3 prints like a mobile display instead of desktop display.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 3):

I found a fix that seems to be working. Got it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49918477/1736012.

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 330mm 427mm;
    margin: 14mm;
  }
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```