# Responsive page goes to mobile when printing

Tags: html, css, frontend

Responsive page goes to mobile when printing and it's not great.

Here's the HTML and CSS used:

HTML:

```
<table class="addr-table">

 <!-- table content -->

</table>
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="window.print()" />
```

CSS:

```
 <style>
        @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600,700';
    
    * {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
    .addr-table {
      margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px ;
      min-width: 240px;
      max-width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      empty-cells: hide;
    }
    .bottom-table {
      margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px ;
      min-width: 200px;
      max-width: 10%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      
    }
    
    .addr-table tr:first-child {
      border-top: none;
      background: #428bca;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .addr-table tr {
      border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      background-color: #f5f9fc;
    }
    
    .addr-table tr:nth-child(odd):not(:first-child) {
      background-color: #ebf3f9;
    }
    
    .addr-table th {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .addr-table td {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .addr-table td:first-child {
      margin-top: .5em;
    }
    
    .addr-table td:last-child {
      margin-bottom: .5em;
    }
    
    .addr-table td:before {
      content: attr(data-th);
      font-weight: bold;
      width: 120px;
      display: inline-block;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    .addr-table th,
    .addr-table td {
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .addr-table {
      color: #333;
      border-radius: .4em;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .addr-table tr {
      border-color: #428bca;
    }
    
    .addr-table th,
    .addr-table td {
      padding: .5em 1em;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 601px) {
      .addr-table tr:nth-child(2) {
        border-top: none;
        
        
      }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
      .addr-table tr:hover:not(:first-child) {
        background-color: #d8e7f3;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .addr-table td:before {
        display: none;
      }
      .addr-table th,
      .addr-table td {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: .25em .5em;
      }
      .addr-table th:first-child,
      .addr-table td:first-child {
        padding-left: 0;
      }
      .addr-table th:last-child,
      .addr-table td:last-child {
        padding-right: 0;
      }
      .addr-table th,
      .addr-table td {
        padding: 1em !important;
      }
    }
    
 
    }

    @media print{
   .hidden-print{
       display:none;
   }
}

    
      </style>
```

Is there a way to prevent some CSS (the @import) from taking effect when printing?
I want it to print in normal PC mode to print as A4 paper not mobile view.

How do I make it NOT to go in responsive/mobile mode when printing?

I thought about putting it in a different template without the responsive CSS but transferring a click to that page will take some JS wizardry which I cannot do, I'm just trying to make a Django app and got caught up in CSS and JS.  Ok I'm writing all this here because I cannot submit, I got "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details".

Comment: Have you already taken a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150929/why-website-printed-with-chrome-is-using-mobile-layout

Comment: Yes I did, not working for me

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prevent some CSS (...) from taking effect when printing?

many ways - each declaration can be dedicated

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">                    <!-- all media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" media="screen">    <!-- only screen -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print">      <!-- only print -->
```

```
@import "https://..." screen;
@import "https://..." screen and (min-width: 600px);
@import "https://..." print;

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { ...
@media only print{ ...
```

Choose one or more of them.
With multiple files declarations order matters since css works as cascade - rules are overwritten if selectors repeat.
Not dedicated css files will be used always.

Comment: Ok, these @import "https: where will I put those?

Comment: I ask bacause I do have two css files one for printing but it seem have affect nothing  <link href=" {% static 'users/crm2/dist/css/print.css' %} " media="print">

Comment: Wherever you want in css - `<style>` in `<head>` or file.css - there where is convenient to you - only add to @import  `print` between `url` and `;`

Comment: And I don't use frameworks :)  - if something is not working it could be a bug or typo use https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/